# Why did the USB connector for the aluminium Apple keyboard have gaps on the plug?

Tags: keyboard, usb

I used to own an Apple USB keyboard - this was the metal version that had a USB port on each end. From memory, the USB cable that connected the keyboard to a computer had several gaps in the connector itself. Out of interest, why was this the case? I recall that a USB extension cable was also included with the keyboard - I wasn't sure if it could be related to this in any way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are referring to the groove in one of the sides of the USB plug on the end of any wired Apple keyboard, it was designed to mate with the included USB extension cable. This extension cable was constructed with a guide inside the female end which allowed *only* the insertion of the cable from the keyboard -- it could not be used as a general USB extension. The male end of the extension cable was without a groove, so stringing two extension cables together was not possible, either. Thanks, Apple.

Keyboard USB connector:

[image]

<sub>And yes, I need to clean the [cruft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruft) from my keyboard. I've been WFH for many hours a day for a few months and there just isn't time.</sub>

Comment: If I remember correctly the USB spel explicite morbid extension cables. I guess this was a way to come round that.

Comment: I suppose this answers "Why was the connector shaped this way?" in the sense of "So that it was the only extension cable allowed", but that just raises the question of "Why did they make it the only extension cable allowed?"

Comment: @jamesdlin Because Apple has a history of trying to force people to use *their* cables, *their* connectors, *their* hardware - or at least, until third parties offer similar things. It was the same when the first iPhone came out and the headphone jack (remember that thing?) was set inside a very small circle. At the time of release, only Apple's earpods would fit into that hole, at least before third parties released adapters or released headphones that would fit.